# Is there a clean way to get the head AND tail of a list in a single expression?

Tags: haskell

Is there something equivalent to

```
(\(x : xs) -> (x, xs)) theList
```

built into the language, to where I could write something like

```
let (h, t) = headAndTail theList in h : t
```

?

Comment: What do you want it to return if the list is empty? Lots of prelude functions like `head` and `tail` are already discouraged for the exact reason that they're not total.

Comment: Does `let (h:t) = theList` fit your purpose?

Comment: `let (h:t) = theList` is pretty nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain old pattern bindings fit the bill.

```
let h:t = theList in h : t
```

Answer (score 5):

`Data.List` provides `uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])`:

```
> uncons "foo"
Just ('f', "oo")
```

If you really want a partial function of type `[a] -> (a, [a])`, you can compose with `Data.Maybe.fromJust`.